# View changes on CVS repository with TortoiseCVS

Tags: diff, cvs, tortoisecvs

Is there a way, with TortoiseCVS, to see what has changed in the repository since the last CVS update?

I am used to Eclipse's synchronize function.  But now I want to view differences in a directory that isn't an eclipse project.

I could check out the project somewhere else and use any diff tool.  But that's ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line version of cvs provides the '-n' option for this purpose. From the cvs manual:

> Do not change any files. Attempt to execute the `cvs_command', but only to issue reports; do not remove, update, or merge any existing
>   files, or create any new files.
>
> Note that CVS will not necessarily produce exactly the same output as without `-n'. In some cases the output will be the same, but in
>   other cases CVS will skip some of the processing that would have been
>   required to produce the exact same output.

The option is also available in Tortoise: Choose "CVS Update Special" from the context menu. In the dialog check the box "Simulate Update" (it's on a separate tab in newer version of Tortoise).

However, I find the feature to be of limited usefulness, due to it's cryptic output and low level of integration (e.g. it's not possible to click on a file and actually view the diff's).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the "simulate option" before.  But it is a start.  This doesn't solve my problem but I guess it answers the question of what TortoiseCVS can do and what it cannot.